# Função que retorna a posição do menor numero em um vetor

Tags: javascript, array

Simples...
Preciso saber qual a **posição** de um valor (o menor valor) dentro de um vetor, para descobrir o menor valor estou usando o `Math.min()`mas para imprimir o resultado eu preciso saber em qual posição o valor esta no vetor. Poderia ser uma função que retorna o a posição *n* no valor no vetor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `Math.min.apply` para achar o menor valor do seu array:

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 0.5, 0.8, 10];
var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);

console.log(min);
```

E pra retornar a posição, você pode usar o indexOf como nas outras respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.indexOf(2)); // retorna 1
```

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input"); // obtem todos os inputs
var valores = []; // vetor para armanezar somente os valores. Esse vetor será usado para obter o minimo entre um conjunto de valores

// funcao que será chamada pelo botão verificar
function verificar(){
  // forEach itera os inputs do formulario
  inputs.forEach(item =>{  
    if (item.value) // se o valor do input for valido (não vazio, nem espacos em branco, nem NaN, etc
      valores.push(parseFloat(item.value)); // empilha (adiciona) na lista de valores
  });
  var menorValor = Math.min.apply(null, valores); //usamos a função Math min para obter o menor valor de um conjunto de valores
  console.log(valores.indexOf(menorValor));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<button onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa o indexOf

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr));
```